# Http post with button activate an internal website

Tags: rest, http

I am creating a project where when I type a url in my web browser it activates a gpio pin on my esp8266 and that works (192.168.2.5/gpio/1). Now I am trying to make a button on my webserver, that when it is pressed it activates that link while staying on the webserver. I dont know if I need http post or what. It doesn't send any data or anything just go to that URL and the pin is activated so I need to implement that as a button on my webserver. If someone can help that would be amazing!

Comment: get / head method is enough !

Comment: check my answer using jquery !

Answer (score 0):

Your web browser is sending a GET request to 192.168.2.5/gpio/1 so you need to mimic that with your code. Use a GET request.

It might help you in the future to get familiar with the different [HTTP verbs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="getmepin" value="get me pin" name=">
```

JS:

```
$( "#getmepin" ).on( "click", function() {
  $.get( "192.168.2.5/gpio/1", function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
  });
});
```